# How to Filter Model with Interface in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my view

```
 Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUSerControl<Model.Person>"
```

How can I use an interface to restrict what the view is capable of accessing from the model? is this safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let *Person* class has several properties and you want only *Name* property be accessible from a view. Declare interface like this and use it:

```
public interface RestrictedPerson
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public partial class Person: RestrictedPerson
{
}
```

in a view's Page directive set

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Model.RestrictedPerson>
```

and pass to view *Person* object as usual.

Comment: is there any way anyone (hacker) could still get to the original object by doing this?

Comment: If he doesn't have access to the hosted application and can't modify source code you shouldn't worry. This can't be hacked from the client side.

Comment: i did this and field from original person were visible in the debugger as pasrt of the Model.